# Inherit template issue regarding flask

Tags: flask, layout

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block body %}

<h1>Profile Page</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Hello I am trying to insert the h1 tag into my page with included layout but the h1 tag does not appears . I've also tried {% block content %} and nothing appears.
I think something is wrong with the layout but for me it seems all alright . You can check it the layout ( https://pastebin.com/aa3S5RsL )
Image with the layout but without h1 tag ( http://tinyimg.io/i/1uwnVdX.PNG )
Please help me if you know what's wrong .

Comment: Where is the code where you call this template? Please show this code in your question. Something like return render_template('hello.html'). Where hello.html is the name of your template that inherits from layout.html. You are sure your layout.html has the same {% %} placeholder?

Comment: `@app.route('/profile')
def profile():
 return render_template('profile.html') `                                                               thats the code from the flask that returns the profile.html

Comment: That seems to look ok. Please also have a look at my other question in my comment. Are both templates in the same template folder?

Comment: Yes they are in the same folder called 'templates'

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a "placeholder" in layout.html for "block body" (or "block content").